# the column index is out of range

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

```sql
select * from crosstab
  ($$ select ord_no,opr_no,prod_qty from sg_tw.at_wrkord_dtl 
  where date(modi_dt)>=(:start_date) 
  and date(modi_dt)<= (:end_date) order by 1,2 $$, $$ values 'ord_no', '10','20','30','40','50','60','70','110' $$) as x
 (ord_no bigint, "10" int, "20" int, "30" int, "40" int, "50" int, "60" int, "70" int ,"110" int)
```

> Error:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.

When I execute this query in my postgressql I am facing this issue.

Please help me to fix this problem.

I am new in IT...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you explain what is in `sg_tw.at_wrkord_dtl` ?  Can you: `select ord_no,opr_no,prod_qty from sg_tw.at_wrkord_dtl ` ? What do you see?

Comment: You "parameters" are inside a string literal, so JDBC won't see them (even if it did recognize named parameters). More often than not it's much easier to used filtered aggregation for a pivot/crosstab query instead of the clumsy `crosstab()` function. Then you don't have to struggle with nesting queries in strings inside function arguments either.

Comment: Thankyou Laurenz Albe..

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the JDBC driver, because that's where that error message comes from.

The problem is that you wrote your parameters as part of a dollar quoted string literal. Parameters in string literals are not replaced.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you are saying?

Comment: @Youzef Well, `:start_date` and `:end_date` are inside a string constant that starts and ends with `$$` (an alternative to single quotes in PostgreSQL). Parameters in string constants are not replaced.

Comment: I can see what you mean. I am using JDBC template. This is the problematic query: `"SELECT * FROM operating_hours WHERE user_id = ?"`. It seems fine to me, but im still getting the error.

Comment: @Youzef Then yours is a different problem. You could ask a new question, which should contain all the relevant code.